# Install maven dependency from location other than Maven Central

Tags: java, maven

I have this pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>interos</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
            <artifactId>cli</artifactId>
            <version>2.49</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.main/cli -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I run

```
mvn install
```

and I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jenkins: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project interos:jenkins:jar:1.0: Failure to find
>   org.jenkins-ci.main:cli:jar:2.49 in
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
>
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

I tried doing this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.maven</id>
        <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://mvnrepository.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But then I got:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jenkins: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project interos:jenkins:jar:1.0: Could not find
>   artifact org.jenkins-ci.main:cli:jar:2.49 in repository.maven
>   (https://mvnrepository.com) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add jenkins repository

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
    <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Because it has the dependency you need, maven central doesn't.

Comment: Yeah but how did you know that? It lists a different repo here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.main/cli/2.49

Comment: Not sure were I got the exact link from, you can use any of the repositories listed there as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solutions (perhaps more):

1. Add also Maven central to the repositories section of your pom file.
2. Add repositories and mirrors to the Maven settings.xml file.

Option 1 and 2 can also be combined.

Another but maybe the best solution is to use your own instance of a Nexus repository manager and load all the dependencies from that Nexus instance (that Nexus should be defined as repository). That Nexus instance should synchronize with/proxy to external repositories like Maven central, Spring, ... and so on.